No encuentro el fallo en el Loop
Tengo una tarea que no he podido resolver. El objetivo es dividir en dos una lista de números. Los números que son divisibles en dos tienen que decir "True", y aquellos que no son divisibles en dos tienen que decir "False". Con en el que no he podido es el 9 porque me dice que es True y no encuentro mi error ahí. Solicito de su asesoría, colegas.
--Mi version del codigo--
def is_power_of_two(number):
 while number % 2 == 2:
    number = number // 1

if number != 1:
   return True
 return False

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be Fals

--Este es el Codigo original de la tarea--
def is_power_of_two(number):

#This while loop check if a "number" can be divide by two without
#leaving a remainder. How can you change the while loop to avoid a
#Python ZeroDivisionError?

While number % 2 == 0:
  number = number / 2


#If after dividing by 2 "number" equals 1, then "number is a power of 2."

if number == 1:
   return True
  return False

#Calls to the function

print(is_power_of_two(0) #Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1) #Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8) #Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9) #Should be False

Me disculpo si no fui muy claro, colegas.

Supongo que vale la pena mencionar también que ese if está fuera de la función... las tabulaciones son lo que define los bloques de código en python, no puede uno inventárselas sin más!

Si asumimos que los problemas de sangrado son fruto de pegar el código aquí, dado que en caso contrario tendríamos un error de sintaxis. Tienes varios problemas de lógica:

Nota: Asumo por la lógica y los tests que la intención es verificar solo las potencias positivas de dos, es decir, la entrada de
la función será un entero siempre.


El operador %, en esencia, retorna el resto de la división entera:
>>> 23 % 4
3

dado que 23 dividido entre 4 son 5 y me quedan 3 de resto.
Esto hace que tu condicional de control del while:
number % 2 == 2

no tenga sentido y jamás se cumplirá. El resto de cualquier número al dividirlo entre 2 no puede ser 2 por definición, es siempre 0 (si la división es exacta) o 1. El while debe terminar cuando encuentre un resto diferente de 0, porque eso indica que el número no es divisible entre 2 y, por tanto, no es una potencia de 2.

El operador // lleva a cabo la división entera. Cuando haces
number = number // 1

estás dividiendo entre 1, la unidad es el elemento neutro de la divisón, un número dividido entre uno da como resultado el mismo número, number nunca cambiará. Si se entra en el ciclo (la condición se cumple al iniciar la primera iteración) este será infinito. Debes dividir entre 2:
number = number // 2


El número será una potencia de dos (su unico factor es el 2) si al final del ciclo number es 1. La última división realizada en estos casos en el ciclo es 2 // 2  que es 1 y ahí termina el ciclo dado que 1 % 2 es 1. Para los casos donde el número no es una potencia de dos, el ciclo termina con un valor de number siempre impar y  mayor a 1 (con una excepción que ahora veremos). Por lo tanto, tu condicional final debe ser:
if number == 1:


Con todo ello nos queda un caso especial que hay que resolver. Si el número de entrada es 0 tendremos un ciclo infinito. 0 % 2 es 0 y 0 // 2  es también 0 por lo que el ciclo jamás terminará. Lo más simple es agregar una condición de entrada que retorne False para todo número menor o igual a 0.


Con todo quedaría algo así:
def is_power_of_two(number: int) -> bool:
    if number <= 0:
        return False
    while number % 2 == 0:
        number = number // 2
    if number == 1:
        return True
    return False

O puedes eliminar el condicional final y simplemente retornar la salida de la comparación:
def is_power_of_two(number: int) -> bool:
    if number <= 0:
        return False
    while number % 2 == 0:
        number //= 2
    return number == 1


Si se quiera hacer esto de forma mucho más eficiente, la respuesta está en las propiedades de la representación binaria de las potencias de dos; en la representacion de los números enteros positivos en binario solo aquellos que son potencias de dos tiene un solo bit establecido en 1 (y la posición que ocupa ese bit se corresponde con el valor del exponente):



Portencia (decimal)
Binario (8 bits uint)




20 = 1
00000001


21 = 2
00000010


22 = 4
00000100


23 = 8
00001000


24 = 16
00010000


25 = 32
00100000


26 = 64
01000000


27 = 128
10000000



Típicamente, se implementa aplicando un and bit a bit entre n y n - 1 (n & (n - 1), que será cero para todo n != 0 que sea una potencia de dos), dado que n - 1 tendrá todos los bits en 1 menos el que es 1 en n. No obstante, int.bit_count() nos viene muy bien en este caso:
def is_power_of_two(number: int) -> bool:
    return number > 0 and number.bit_count() == 1

La diferencia en tiempo de ejecución es muy significativa si trabajamos con potencias grandes:
n = 2 ** 231185

%%timeit
is_power_of_two_iterative_divmod(n)


7.22 s ± 8.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


%%timeit
is_power_of_two_bit_count(n)


17.8 µs ± 2.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)



Para comprobar que un número es divisible por otro, sólo tienes que ver el resto de la división:
Si un número es divisible por 2, el resto de la división debe ser cero. No es necesario una iteración.
def is_power_of_two(number):
    return number % 2 == 0

Eso soluciona el problema.
Ahora, parece que tu problema es con la "potencias de 2" (no está muy claro). En ese caso, debes repetir reemplazando el valor original por el valor dividido por 2, hasta llegar a uno:
def is_power_of_two(number):
    while number > 1 and number % 2 == 0:
        number = number // 2

    return number == 1

La función entra en un ciclo iterativo mientras el número sea mayor que 1 y el resto igual a cero. Si luego de reducir el numero éste queda igual a 1, quiere decir que llegamos al final de la secuencia y el número es potencia de dos.

Yo pondría el if fuera del ciclo while, pues no hace falta comprobarlo en cada iteración, basta con comprobarlo una vez al final.

@jachguate. Gracias
